# Search did not display result properly

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

I have trouble getting data from an array then search it in my search box. It only shows one result which is the first item.

I think this is the code being called:

```
ViewOrders.this.orderArrayAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
```

Other than that is there other option to get a search function?

Here is my code:

```
Class A
    private OrdersList orderArrayAdapter;

    private void setupAdapterOrdersList() {
        orderArrayAdapter = new OrdersList(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row_item_view_orders, ordersArray);
        if (orderListView != null) {
            orderListView.setAdapter(orderArrayAdapter);
        }
    }

private void searchFromListView() {
        etSearch = findViewById(R.id.search_order);

        /**
         * Enabling Search Filter
         * */
        etSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // When user changed the Text
                ViewOrders.this.orderArrayAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
    }

Class B
package com.example.android.ontrack.adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.android.ontrack.R;
import com.example.android.ontrack.models.Order;

public class OrdersList extends ArrayAdapter<Order> {

    Context mContext;
    int mLayoutResourceId;
    Order mData[] = null;

    public OrdersList(Context context, int resource, Order[] data) {
        super(context, resource, data);
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mLayoutResourceId = resource;
        this.mData = data;
    }


    @Override
    public Order getItem(int position) {
        return super.getItem(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row;

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        row = inflater.inflate(mLayoutResourceId, parent, false);

        TextView nameOfSchool = row.findViewById(R.id.school_name_orders);
        TextView nameOfAgent = row.findViewById(R.id.agent_name);
        TextView orderId = row.findViewById(R.id.order_id);
        TextView netRevenue = row.findViewById(R.id.net_revenue);
        TextView orderQuantity = row.findViewById(R.id.total_quantity);
        TextView date = row.findViewById(R.id.date);

        Order orders = mData[position];

        nameOfSchool.setText(orders.nameOfSchool);
        nameOfAgent.setText(String.valueOf(orders.nameOfAgent));
        orderId.setText(String.valueOf(orders.orderId));
        netRevenue.setText(String.valueOf(orders.netRevenue));
        orderQuantity.setText(String.valueOf(orders.totalQuantity));
        date.setText(String.valueOf(orders.date));

        return row;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to implement `Filterable` in your `ArrayAdapter` and override `getFilter()`.

Comment: how? can you have an example?

Comment: I don't know how to do Filterable. Please give me an example.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.